# Borderlands 2 DLC challenge "C4 is for Cookie"

Tags: borderlands-2

I'm playing the Borderlands 2 DLC Torgue Campaign of Carnage and for the challenge "C4 is for Cookie" you must destroy 6 boxes of cookies. I found 5, but I can't find the 6th box of cookies.

Where is the last box of cookies? Can it be located before the end of the "Breaking and Entering" quest?

Comment: Unless the title does not make a proper sentence, there is nothing wrong with it. Please don't make meaningless changes to posts. The original title was a good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Starting from the entrance, which is marked by the green diamond in
>   the map below and proceeding along the outer ring (counter-clockwise
>   on the map), the storage areas holding the cookies boxes are the
>   first, second, and fourth rooms initially. Beyond the two conjoined
>   rooms there are cookie boxes in the seventh and eighth rooms.
>
> The most commonly-overlooked cookie box is not in fact in a storage
>   room, but within the hidden basement room; the top-middle map marker
>   in the image below.  The hidden room is sealed beneath a grate, which
>   can be opened by stepping on a hexagonal gray button in the floor
>   nearby.
>   [image]

[Source](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/C4_Is_For_Cookie)